# Map Infopath Form to SharePoint Document for Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, infopath

**Situation:**

I have a request to create a InfoPath form to request new product be brought into a company. Once an End User makes the request, they are assigned a task to upload the required documentation pdf file to the correct SharePoint Doc Library.

**Question:**

Is there a way to relate the pdf file to the Infopath from in order to copy some of the InfoPath form's information to the metadata of the pdf?

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question correctly,
Yes, you can add a file input to the infopath form.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/insert-a-file-attachment-control-8e8e102f-fad5-4440-bc28-d28944f85287

This could be in a different view of the form because its in a different "state"(after request it goes to review), where the PDF could be uploaded.

I am pretty sure this can be saved as a document in a separate library or as a file attachment in the list.

Comment: Can you please add brief details from the link.

Comment: When I try to use the file attachment field, I'm not able to access it from SPD because I'm unable to set it as an available column in the SharePoint list.